# \cite not working

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cross-referencing, citing

I have been trying to solve this on my own but I can't seem to find a solution. Whenever I use, `\cite{schneider_2002}`, in the PDF it just shows "schneider_2002". It happens with any element in my .bib file. Here is an example of my references.bib file:

```
@book{schneider_2002,
    address = {Pittsburgh},
    title = {E-{Prime} {Reference} {Guide}},
    publisher = {Psychology Software Tools, Inc},
    author = {Schneider, W and Eschman, A and Zuccolotto, A},
    year = {2002}
}
```

And here is the preamble of my .tex file:

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber,]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

I have tried **\cite**, **\parencite** and **\textcite**, but they don't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Not related to the problem at hand, but given name initials should be marked with a dot: **`author = {Schneider, W. and Eschman, A. and Zuccolotto, A.},`** instead of `author = {Schneider, W and Eschman, A and Zuccolotto, A},`. With a current version of `biblatex-apa` you won't need `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}`. If you want full APA style you shouldn't say `sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,`, `style=apa,` already sets the required options.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will delete them.

Comment: One last thing, the example entry may be more of a `@manual` than an actual `@book`. (But that probably doesn't change a lot.)